# Tool for executing select SQL (similar to bare tail for text editor)

Tags: sql-server

I need to get error logs from a database. When ever new error occurs, it will be inserted into that table. Is there any tool available for viewing it instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write our own web app for doing it.
Write some insert trigger & update your app accordingly.